# Launch RoyalSlider from list of thumbnails

Tags: jquery, slider

I'm trying to launch a fullscreen instance of RoyalSlider dynamically from a list of non-scrolling thumbnails.

HTML:

```
<div class="royalSlider rsDefault">
    <a class="rsImg" data-rsBigImg="http://wordpress.ms/college-news/wp-content/uploads/sites/3/2014/01/NICOLA.jpg" href="http://wordpress.ms/college-news/wp-content/uploads/sites/3/2014/01/NICOLA.jpg">yay caption!<img width="150" height="150" class="rsTmb" src="http://wordpress.ms/college-news/wp-content/uploads/sites/3/2014/01/NICOLA-150x150.jpg" /></a>
    <a class="rsImg" data-rsBigImg="http://wordpress.ms/college-news/wp-content/uploads/sites/3/2014/01/NICOLA.jpg" href="http://wordpress.ms/college-news/wp-content/uploads/sites/3/2014/01/NICOLA.jpg">yay caption!<img width="150" height="150" class="rsTmb" src="http://wordpress.ms/college-news/wp-content/uploads/sites/3/2014/01/NICOLA-150x150.jpg" /></a>
    <a class="rsImg" data-rsBigImg="http://wordpress.ms/college-news/wp-content/uploads/sites/3/2014/01/NICOLA.jpg" href="http://wordpress.ms/college-news/wp-content/uploads/sites/3/2014/01/NICOLA.jpg">yay caption!<img width="150" height="150" class="rsTmb" src="http://wordpress.ms/college-news/wp-content/uploads/sites/3/2014/01/NICOLA-150x150.jpg" /></a>
</div>
```

JS:

```
// RoyalSlider
$(".royalSlider").on("click", ".rsTmb", function(event) {

    event.preventDefault();

    var index = $(event.target).parent().index();

    var slider = $(".royalSlider").royalSlider({
            keyboardNavEnabled: true,
            controlNavigation: 'thumbnails',
            globalCaption:true,
            globalCaptionInside: false,
            fullscreen: {
                enabled: true
            },
            thumbs: {
                // thumbnails options go gere
                spacing: 10,
                arrowsAutoHide: true
            }
        }).data('royalSlider');

    if (!slider.isFullscreen) { // not fullscreen

        slider.enterFullscreen();
        slider.goTo(index); // this quite often does not find the index

    }
});
```

**UPDATE:** this code works to transition from a list of thumbs to fullscreen and back again. However I'm still having problems arriving at the correct slide after returning to fullscreen.

e.g.

1. Page loads, thumbs appear -> works
2. Click thumb, loads fullscreen -> works
3. Exit fullscreen -> works
4. Click another thumb that is not the current ID -> fullscreen loads but with the wrong image, or half an image (it's like the slider location gets out of sync)

Answer (score 0):

Native HTML5 fullscreen can be executed only via user action (i.e. click).

You may disable native fullscreen via option - http://dimsemenov.com/plugins/royal-slider/documentation/#fullscreen

Or just stretch slider to 100% width/height of window at start http://help.dimsemenov.com/kb/royalslider-jquery-plugin-faq/how-stretch-slider-to-full-browser-width-and-height

Comment: Thanks for this, I've updated my JS code to show work in progress. I've got it working but the fullscreen slides can get out of sync with their thumbs. Any further tips appreciated.